# using theme check plugin to remove waring and errors from my theme

Tags: theme-development, genesis-theme-framework

i have solve the most of issue now only the followings issue reaming.

1.the most important

WARNING: curl_init was found in the file twitteroauth.php File operations should use the WP_Filesystem methods instead of direct PHP filesystem calls.

Line 195: $ci = curl_init();

WARNING: curl_exec was found in the file twitteroauth.php File operations should use the WP_Filesystem methods instead of direct PHP filesystem calls.

Line 221: $response = curl_exec($ci);

Comment: And what is your question, the warning are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: i have clearly mention it in the title i want to remove all these it should says me that your theme passed

Comment: @sultan I think you understood what the plugin said you. Try googling all those new term and you will get your way to fix 'em. I agree with Wyck, you are asking a question where the answer is within.

Comment: yes i have google it but the above issue which i m unable to find

Comment: See the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) for the Filesystem API, there have also helpful links. Replace the curl with this WP API.